# FileNotFound error while reading images from GDrive in Colab

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I am trying to manipulate images stored in different image directories in my Google Drive for deep learning. However, I'm getting a `FileNotFound` exception.

Suppose, my main directory in Google Colab is :

```
MainDirectory ='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/'
```

And there are two directories within that folder called `Dog` and `Cat`. I can verify this by running following code:

```py
MainDirectory ='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/'
Categories =['Dog','Cat']

for category in Categories:
    path = os.path.join(MainDirectory,category)
    print(path)
```

which prints the directories :

```py
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/Dog
/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/Cat
```

What I'm trying to do now is show the images, for which I wrote the following piece of code:

```py
MainDirectory = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/'
Categories =['Dog','Cat']
for category in Categories:
   path =os.path.join(MainDirectory,category)
   print(path)
    
   for img in os.listdir(path):
      img_array =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
      plt.imshow(img_array,cmap="gray")
      plt.show()
```

However this results in the following error:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/Dog'
```

Additional information

---

I have imported the following libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
```

And mounted my drive using following command :

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: I just used your example code in my local directory, creating a folder called "My Drive" and including different subfolders with spaces and images and it runs without problems. 
Probably the problem comes from the drive.mount()

Comment: what a strange, i have signout and  sign in again but not  effect

Comment: but  strange thing is that it can see  actual path /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/Dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely caused by the spaces in the filepath. Add the `r` string literal prefix before the `MainDirectory` file path, to use as a raw string. Here is the corrected code:

```
MainDirectory = r'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/'
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file paths exist?

Comment: Then, I am not sure. Perhaps the capitalization?

Comment: look it can see directory /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/2020YearDeepLearning/Animals/PetImages/Dog

Comment: Hmm... please copy and paste the path to one of the images

Comment: Path is given my friend, images are in Dog folder and  also  in cat folder

Comment: I opened my google colab and connected to a runtime, and MyDrive didn't have a space between. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: This is how you mounted your drive right?:
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Comment: If you have time, we can move this discussion to chat

Comment: it was strange space  which i could not see,  sorry for wasting your time

Comment: r-strings don't differ from normal strings in their handling of spaces. they only differ in their handling of backslashes.